# jQuery accordion-like menu with text replace

Tags: jquery

I want to indicate a menu's expandability/collapsibility with a 'plus' sign. I want to replace the plus sign with a minus when the item has been expanded.

The only issue at the moment is returning the minus back to a plus when I click on another item.

Any suggestions?

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/saltcod/Lg9Mn/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this - http://jsfiddle.net/Lg9Mn/2/

```
jQuery(function($){
    var allMetaFields = $('.meta-field').hide();

    $('.topics-meta h3').on('click', function(){
        $('.topics-meta span').text('+');
        $(this).find('span').text('-');
        allMetaFields.slideUp();

        if ( $(this).next().is(":visible") ) {
            $(this).find('span').text('+');
        } else {
            $(this).next().slideDown();
        }

        return false;
    });
});
```

Comment: Heads up, menus won't stay collapsed so you will always have one open using this method. It's close, but not perfect.

Comment: Yeah, it definitely isn't perfect.